# Connect dApp hosted on cloud with Geth running locally

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development, web3.py, aws

I've my dApp running on AWS and Geth running locally. How am I supposed to connect my hosted dApp with the Geth?

I'm connecting my web3(using web3.py) using my computer's(Windows OS) IP address.

```
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8545"))
```

Port 8545 has been also opened via Firewall port.

Running my Geth node using

```
geth --datadir ./Doc-Nodes --networkid 4780 --rpc --rpcapi "db,personal,eth,net,web3,debug,admin" --rpccorsdomain="*" --rpcaddr="0.0.0.0" --rpcport 8545 --allow-insecure-unlock console
```

But I'm always getting the error while sending the request to dApp.

> requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout:
>   HTTPConnectionPool(host='xx.xx.xx.xx', port=8545): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: / (Caused by
>   ConnectTimeoutError(urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at)

How am I supposed to connect both? I'm confused about what IP should be provided in the web3 connection as well as rpc address.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `--rpcvhosts *` too

Comment: It's still not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a reverse ssh connection on a host with public ip of your property, or otherwise use ngrok for the reverse ssh.

**host= public ip**

```
$ssh -R 8545:localhost:<port> user@<host>

$ngrok tcp 8545

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://<host>:<port>")) //or ngrok link connection with port
```